# Is there any need to change the migration file version to[6.0] while upgrading from rails 4.2 to rails6.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I upgraded my rails 4.2 project to rails5.2 and then now to rails6.0.
One of my old migration file is:

```
class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :locations do |t|
      t.string :name, :limit=>100, :null=>false      
      t.string :address1, :limit=>60, :null=>false
      t.string :address2, :limit=>60, :null=>false
      t.string :city, :limit=>30, :null=>false
      t.string :state, :limit=>30, :null=>false
      t.string :zip, :limit=>15, :null=>false     
      t.boolean :status
      t.references :user      
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Now, I updated the first line to:

```
class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
```

Is it correct, or I need to give the new version [6.0] for existing old migration files.
Please help

Comment: The thing is that you should be using your `schema.rb` file as the source of truth for the database schema, not running the migrations again. There is however a nice article here on this stuff https://bigbinary.com/blog/migrations-are-versioned-in-rails-5

Comment: You should probably delete any migration more than a couple months old and go with `schema.rb` or `structure.sql` as @Eyeslandic says. Migrations are meant to get you from A to B, they're not permanent, so once they've been applied everywhere they can be deleted.

Comment: There can be rare cases when old migrations are in fact needed - for example if project has db triggers/stored functions or other features not covered by standard rails schema and developers forgot to switch from schema.rb to structure.sql. Other rare case - restoring an old backup and migrations manipulate data.

Answer (score 1):

For old migrations you should have `ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]`, this is for migration compatibility so that migration will have same effect on newer rails (rails 5 changed migrations api, for example default options are different).

In general - migrations now have the rails version they were initially created on, and after upgrade run similarly (or fail, but at least not silently produce unexpected results)